# Link and add items to a dictionary from another class

Tags: vb.net, class, dictionary

I have a dictionary structured like:

```
Public Structure MyStruct
    Dim X as Integer
    Dim Y as Integer
    Dim Z as Integer
    Dim W as Integer
End Structure

Public Shared MyDic As New Dictionary(Of String, MyStruct)
```

I need to insert some data into the dictionary through a function that is in another class. How can I link `MyDic` and `MyStruct` to the class in order to add the data into the dictionary?

The general situation would be like:

```
Public Class myFirstForm
    Public Structure MyStruct
        Dim X as Integer
        Dim Y as Integer
        Dim Z as Integer
        Dim W as Integer
    End Structure

    Public Shared MyDic As New Dictionary(Of String, MyStruct)
End Class

Public Class myClass
    Public Sub mySub()
        Dim Struct as New MyStruct
        'Some code
        MyDic.Add("FirstElement",Struct)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by doing:

```
Public Class MyForm()
    Public Shared myDic As New Dictionary(Of String, MyClass.myStruct)
End Class

Public Class MyClass()
    Private Shared myDic As New Dictionary(Of String, Proprieta)
    Public Structure myStruct
        Dim x as Integer
        Dim y as Integer
        Dim z as Integer
        Dim t as Integer
    End Structure
    Public Sub mySub(prepareDic as Dictionary(Of String, Proprieta))
        myDic = prepareDic 
        'My Code
    End Sub
End Class
```